# How to prevent removal of slots from a certain signal?

Tags: c++, boost-signals

Is it possible to block the removal of certain slots from a signal in the boost.signals library?
If so how should a code that does such a thing will look like?  Do I need to create a derived class just for that specific signal to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply your own slot connection function that fails to return the connection.  Without the connection the client can't break it.

Edit: code example:

```
struct my_class
{
  boost::signals::connection listen_event1(boost::function<void (my_class const&)> const& f)
  {
    return signal1.connect(f);
  }
  void listen_event2(boost::function<void my_class const&)> const& f)
  {
    signal2.connect(f);
  }

private:
  typedef boost::signals::signal<void(my_class const&)> sig_t;
  sig_t signal1;
  sig_t signal2;
};
```

signal2 connections cannot be disconnected.

Comment: You mean that my signal will be a special signal that derives the original one? Will it have two connect functions? One that accepts a removable connection and one that accepts a non-removable connection? Or do you mean that I should supply a function that connects but doesn't return a connection? How can I overload the return type?

Comment: No.  Hopefully you're not exposing your signal object publicly, right?  You have functions in the class that generates signals that allows you to connect with them.  Just don't return the boost::signals::connection object that is returned by the signal object you're using to implement that signal.

Comment: I am exposing those signals through getters. I've seen it done in http://www.webtoolkit.eu (Wt)

Comment: Well, guess now you know why that's not necessarily a good idea.  I'd refactor so that those signal objects are encapsulated.  Then you can block disconnection by not returning the connection.  I don't know of any other way to get what you want.